# Getting Error 1052 When trying to join 3 tables together with inner join

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble using an inner join to join 3 tables together.
The tables are as follows.

mysql> `SELECT * FROM tbldvdactors;`

| ACTORID | FName | LName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Val | Kilmer |
| 2 | Johnny | Depp |
| 3 | John | Cleese |
| 4 | Michael | Keaton |
| 5 | Roy | Scheider |

mysql> `SELECT * FROM tbldvdtitles;`

| ASIN | Title | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6304711905 | Tombstone | 1.95 |
| 783229526 | Fear and Loathing in Las Vegas | 8.46 |
| B00005O3VC | Monty Python and the Holy Grail | 8.88 |
| B001CCIRG4 | Beetlejuice | 9.60 |
| B007STBUHI | Jaws | 7.62 |

mysql> `SELECT * FROM tblrelantionships;`

| ASIN | ACTORID |
| --- | --- |
| 6304711905 | 1 |
| 783229526 | 2 |
| B0000503VC | 3 |
| B001CCIRG4 | 4 |
| B007STBUHI | 5 |

Here is the command I am using

```
    mysql> SELECT ASIN, Title, ACTOR_ID, FName, LName, Price
    -> FROM tblrelantionships
    -> INNER JOIN tbldvdtitles
    -> ON tblrelantionships.ASIN = tbldvdtitles.ASIN
    -> INNER JOIN tbldvdactors
    -> ON tblrelantionships.ACTORID = tbldvdactors.ACTORID;
    ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'ASIN' in field list is ambiguous
```

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can provide.

Comment: Qualify the column name with the table name like `tbldvdtitles.ASIN`You have 2 tables with an ASIN column, you need to tell MySQL which one you want to see, otherwise if you ask it to guess, it may get the wrong one, so it does not even try to guess

Answer (score 0):

The ASIN column is defined in more than one table, so you have to explicitly select one.
Using tables aliases makes query shorter and easier to read IMHO.

```
SELECT 
   tt.ASIN, tt.Title, ta.ACTOR_ID, ta.FName, ta.LName, tt.Price
FROM tblrelantionships tr
INNER JOIN tbldvdtitles tt 
   ON tr.ASIN = tt.ASIN
INNER JOIN tbldvdactors ta 
   ON tr.ACTORID = ta.ACTORID;
```

Answer (score 0):

On the first line, you should specify the table from which you are selecting the field ANSI. Try this:

```
 mysql> SELECT tblrelantionships.ASIN, Title, ACTOR_ID, FName, LName, Price
-> FROM tblrelantionships
-> INNER JOIN tbldvdtitles
-> ON tblrelantionships.ASIN = tbldvdtitles.ASIN
-> INNER JOIN tbldvdactors
-> ON tblrelantionships.ACTORID = tbldvdactors.ACTORID;
```